# Three-digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

How many three-digit numbers are divisible by $ 11 $?

Attemp: 
The list goes 110,121,132....990.

That's just 10,11,12...90.

Subtract 9 from the list, we get 81.

Answer should be $\boxed{81}$

Correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @lulu I think I forgot to consider that the digits are distinct

Comment: I think you have to see the condition of the digits being distinct

Comment: I suggest you delete this post and post a new question, with all the details added.   As a hint:  work backwards and count the cases with two more duplicate digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already stated in a comment, this is correct.

(Since I've twice now received delete votes for such answers, I might add that I'm writing this as a community wiki post so that the question doesn't remain unanswered, clogging the system, as there's nothing more to say beyond what's already been said in the comments.)

Comment: I think I forgot to consider that the digits are distinct

Comment: @Tortugut: I'm not sure how you mean you forgot to "consider" it. It's not part of the problem statement. If you forgot it, you forgot to state it in the problem. I agree with lulu; if that's the case, you should post a new question including everything in the problem that you want included.